# Error: after default apache port change

Tags: apache-2.2

```
service httpd restart
```

Error:

```
Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:4508
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:4508
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

Comment: are you running this command as root?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a SELinux issue. By default, SELinux allows `httpd` to listen only on standart 80 port. Run `# semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 4508`. `semanage` utility is contained in `policycoreutils-python` package.